# How get how many video (in seconds) is buffered from MP4 file (Flash, AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Good day!

I can get which part of file in bytes is loaded using `netstream.bytesLoaded`, `netstream.bytesTotal`, I can get the current playing position using `netstream.time`. But I want to know how many seconds of video are already loaded (not the length of buffer, which remains constant).

The loaded size in bytes is not directly proportional to running time of the video.

Any help is really appriciated!

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Yep, it was quite long time ago, but as far as I remember we used keyframe information from file metadata. There you will have time to file position mappings. Using this and `bytesLoaded` you can estimate what time is loaded pretty accurate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the video codec / compression strategy used.  I would do something naive and estimate it based on:

```
var secondsOfBuffer:Number = duration * (bytesLoaded/bytesTotal) - playPosition;
```

this would give you a rough estimate assuming the video has been encoded in a streaming format.

Comment: For my mp4 files size is not proportional to length in seconds, I suppose that's because mp4 is adaptive. So for now I use seekpoints to estimate how much of video was loaded (in seconds).

Comment: right, that's why i said it depends on the codec / compression strategy.